# onActivityResult() is giving null data in my code for capturing an image and uploading it to Firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to capture an image from my app and then uploading it to firebase storage. I am trying to pass the captured image though intent. However, the onActivityResult() method is always showing null data.

This is for a note taking app that I am building. On clicking the camera icon from the app, the camera app of the phone should open and upon capturing, the resulting image should be uploaded to firebase.
I am attaching my code for the same.

```
    private static final int Camera_Request_Code = 1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1
            );
        }

        mCaptureBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Camera_Request_Code);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Camera_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            mProgress.setMessage("Uploading image");
            mProgress.show();

            Log.d("...............",""+data.getData());
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filePath=mStorage.child("Images").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,"Uploading finished",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
   }

    }
```

The error:
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference

Comment: obviously `uri.getLastPathSegment()` is null

Comment: Even data.getData() is showing null in the log. Hence uri is null. What is the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occurs because the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()` is null:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
```

[The documentation for capturing a camera image](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) explains:

> The Android Camera application saves a full-size photo if you give it
> a file to save into. **You must provide a fully qualified file name
> where the camera app should save the photo**.

Follow the example in the documentation to create a file Uri and add it to the intent for the camera app.

Comment: No luck. Even after saving the captured image and passing the uri of the saved image as putExtra(), onActivityResult() is throwing nullpointer exception where I try to access the extra.

Comment: Thanks! I figured the error and now it is working perfectly fine